# How to fit data in the form of vectors to Gumbel copula in R?

Tags: r, statistics, data-fitting

I am relatively new to R. For my final exam at university I decided to write a dissertation on copulas and so I collected some knowledge of the theory behind copulas, what they are and how they work. I also program in R but have never used copulas in R therefore I am a novice to copulas in R.

My question is:
how can I fit raw data (in the form of an R vector) to a Gumbel copula?

Here is the format of my data:

```
x <- c(x1,x2,x3,...,xn)
y <- c(y1,y2,y3,...,yn)
```

Right now I'm using the copula package, I know how to generate random copulas and Gumbel copulas given theta as below:

```
#independence case
r_matrix <- t(rgumbel(2000,theta=1))
plot(r_matrix[1,], r_matrix[2,], col="blue", main="Gumbel, independence case")
positive dependence
r_matrix <- t(rgumbel(2000,theta=3))
plot(r_matrix[1,], r_matrix[2,], col="blue", main="Gumbel, Positive dependence")
```

However I do not know how to estimate theta.. I know what Spearman's Rho and Kendall's Tau are, if that could help.
Could you please help me to fit x and y to the Gumbel copula? Should I use another package? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
library(copula)
gumbel.cop= gumbelCopula(2, dim = 7)
set.seed(117)
u1 = rCopula(500, gumbel.cop)
fit.ml = fitCopula(gumbel.cop, u1, method = "ml")
```

The output for the above is

```
fitCopula() estimation based on 'maximum likelihood'
and a sample of size 500.
      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
param  2.01132    0.02902   69.31   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
The maximized loglikelihood is  1643 
Optimization converged
Number of loglikelihood evaluations:
function gradient 
      20        3
```

You can also try "mpl","itau" or "irho" instead of "ml" for the estimator. Just so you know
"ml" is (maximum likelihood),
"mpl" is (maximum pseudo-likelihood), "itau" is (inversion of Kendall’s
tau), and "irho"  is (inversion of Spearman’s rho). See [R copula package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/copula.pdf) for more details